# Calling an Oracle procedure with a PL/SQL collection type parameter via .NET

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call an Oracle stored procedure via .NET. Normally this isn't a problem, but this stored procedure contains a parameter that is a PL/SQL collection type:

```
create or replace type test_type as table of number;
PROCEDURE TEST1 (pvTest IN test_type);
```

This is my C# code:

```
var receiverIds = new decimal[] { 683552, 683553, 683572, 683573, 683592, 683593, 683594, 683612 };
var receiversList = new OracleParameter("pvTest", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);
receiversList.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
receiversList.Size = receiverIds.Length;
receiversList.Value = receiverIds;

using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand())
{
    oracleCommand.Connection = this.oracleConnection;
    oracleCommand.CommandText = "test_package.TEST1";
    oracleCommand.BindByName = true;

    oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When I execute this, I get the "ORA-06550: Wrong number or type of arguments" error. In this topic: [ORA-06550: Wrong number or type of arguments error | Calling Oracle Procedure with Table type IN parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624284/ora-06550-wrong-number-or-type-of-arguments-error-calling-oracle-procedure-wi) I found that I should declare my custom type inside my package.

So I created a test package that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_package_gkeu IS
    TYPE test_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

    PROCEDURE TEST1 (pvTest IN test_type);
END test_package_gkeu;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_package_gkeu IS
    PROCEDURE TEST1 (pvTest IN test_type) IS
    BEGIN
      null;
    END TEST1;
END test_package_gkeu;
/
```

However, this still produced the exact same error. After some more searching and trying I found that I need to add "INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER" to "test_type" and that works, with this I can call my procedure without errors.

Then I started adding the SQL query from the original procedure to this test package:

```
select *
from receiver r
where r.receiverid in (select /*+cardinality(t 5)*/ *
from table(cast((pvTest) as test_type)) t
where rownum >= 0);
```

But now I cannot build my package anymore. I found the following on StackOverflow ([PlSQL Invalid data type even after casting why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925930/plsql-invalid-data-type-even-after-casting-why)):

> PL/SQL types defined in package are invisible to SQL statements: they are pure PLSQL constructs and the SQL language can't access them directly.

And [somewhere else](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/declaration.html) I found:

> Index by tables cannot be declared globally; the following construct generates a PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context.

So I'm in a dilemma here. I can't call the procedure if the custom type doesn't have an "INDEX BY", I can't use this type in a query when I declare it in the package and I can't declare it globally due to the "INDEX BY".

Could anyone help me out? I guess I need to find a way to call the procedure when the type doesn't have an "INDEX BY", but I've tried everything I could think of or find.

ps. I'm using .NET 4.5 and [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/) v 4.121.1.0 and our Oracle database is, unfortunately, still 10g (10.2.0.4.0).

Comment: Interesting question! When googling for this, i found this article on codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141728/Interaction-between-C-Application-and-Oracle-throu . You should be able to skip the chapter "Receive Data as Custom Object from Oracle Store Procedure" and use the other code samples from that article to adapt them to your problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this article is applicable for my problem. I just have a simple PLSQLAssociativeArray, I don't really need a custom object. 

Also, the Enumeration "OracleDbType" doesn't even contain "Object" anymore and I can't find much about it. Looks like it's just old and deprecated.

Comment: "INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER" was a real game changer. Thanks for highlighting. We were ignoring that and it was not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Procedure call via ODP.NET supports only Associative arrays, i.e. with `INDEX BY ...`, Nested Tables are not supported.

One solution is to convert in in your Orale procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_package_gkeu IS

    TYPE test_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;    
    TYPE test_type_associative IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY INTEGER;

PROCEDURE TEST1 (pvTest IN test_type_associative ) IS

v test_type := test_type();
BEGIN
   v.Extend(pvTest.COUNT);
   for i in pvTest.First..pvTest.Last loop
       v(i) := pvTest(i)
   end loop;

select *
into ...
from receiver r
where r.receiverid MEMBER OF (v);

END;
```

For DML statements consider also this:

```
FORALL i IN INDICES OF pvTest 
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (COL_A)
    VALUES (pvTest(i));

or 

FORALL i IN INDICES OF pvTest 
    DELETE FROM receiver 
    WHERE receiverid  = pvTest(i);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This fixed our problem :)
I'm curious though, you said "One solution is...", so what would be other solutions? It's not that I don't like this solution, I'm just curious about the other possible solutions.